# Internal Excation [Call to undefined function mb_convert_encoding ()]

Tags: php

При запуске приложения с консоли выдает следующую ошибку

> Internal Exception [Call to undefined function `mb_convert_encoding()`].

Насколько я понимаю, она связана с отсутствием `mbstring`. В файле `php.ini` раскомментировала строку с `extension=mb_srting` и это не помогло.
Подскажите, как настроить `mb_string`?

Comment: апач перезапустите. да и посмотрите phpinfo, чтобы убедиться, что расширение действительно загружено и вы исправили нужный ini-файл

Comment: @teran при чём тут апач? Говорят же "При запуске приложения с консоли"

Comment: @ZhukovRoman ах точно, пропустил момент.  тогда php-cli.ini править надо а не php.ini

Comment: Расширение mbstring вообще установлено в системе?

Comment: Я добавляла, но не видно того, чтобы оно включалось.